# JQuery : document.querySelector not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to achieve the following code snippet at end:

1. Need the `var menulinks = document.querySelector('.nav-wrap a');` to
   select all of the `<a>` tags in the div, not just the first one.
2. Add simple function - trigger the `menulinks` function (basically
   closes the menu pane), then looks if the `<a>` tag has `#` to a
   corresponding page anchor, if yes, smooth-scroll to tag. This
   function would ideally, work as above but could maybe be used
   sitewide for smooth scrolling anchors.
3. Finally, any general cleanup suggestions for the code, or ways to
   simplify it further would be helpful, still learning JQuery.

```js
var menu = document.querySelector('.nav-btn');
var menulinks = document.querySelector('.nav-wrap a'); //FOR EACH STATEMENT?

function toggleMenu(event) {
  'use strict';
  if (!menu.classList.contains('active')) {
    menu.classList.add('active');
    $(".nav-wrap").addClass("nav-push");
  } else {
    menu.classList.remove('active');
    $(".nav-wrap").removeClass("nav-push");
  }
  event.preventDefault();
}
menu.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu, false);
menulinks.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu, false);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried the "All" at the end but it did not seem to work. I was reading somewhere that if I use the All, I need to have a for each statement somewhere in the code, but could not seem to make it work.

Comment: Why `querySelector(All)` when using jQuery? Or more generally, why are you mixing so much *vanilla-javascript* when using jQuery?

Comment: @Yoshi - Like I said I am still learning Javascript, I am teaching myself. I do not mean for it to seem Vanilla, but I am trying to keep it simple, clean and functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all elements matching the given selector.

But then you need to iterate over the set of elements and add the click handler.

```js
var menu = document.querySelector('.nav-btn');
var menulinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-wrap a');

function toggleMenu(event) {
  'use strict';
  if (!menu.classList.contains('active')) {
    menu.classList.add('active');
    $(".nav-wrap").addClass("nav-push");
  } else {
    menu.classList.remove('active');
    $(".nav-wrap").removeClass("nav-push");
  }
  event.preventDefault();
}

menu.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu, false);
for (var i = 0; i < menulinks.length; i++) {
  menulinks[i].addEventListener('click', toggleMenu, false);
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: green
}
.nav-push {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="nav-btn">nav-btn</button>
<div class="nav-wrap">
  <a href="#">1</a><br />
  <a href="#">2</a><br />
  <a href="#">3</a><br />
</div>
```

---

But since you have jQuery

```js
$('.nav-btn, .nav-wrap a').click(function() {
  $('.nav-btn').toggleClass('active');
  $(".nav-wrap").toggleClass("nav-push", $('.nav-btn').hasClass('active'));
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: green
}
.nav-push {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="nav-btn">nav-btn</button>
<div class="nav-wrap">
  <a href="#">1</a><br />
  <a href="#">2</a><br />
  <a href="#">3</a><br />
</div>
```

Comment: The second example worked like a charm and eliminated half of the code. You rock!